# Can setuptools setup.py define multiple packages and how do I reference them individually?

Tags: python, setuptools

I maintain a [Python REST micro framework](https://github.com/anomaly/prestans.git). It's installable via setuptools and is available on [PyPi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/prestans/). Certain features offered by the framework are only relevant for development and shouldn't really be available in production environments.

If I configure setuptools as follows and install it in a virualenv things do seem to work.

```
setup(name='prestans',
      version = __version__,
      install_requires = ['WebOb>=1.5',],
...
)

setup(name='prestans-devel',
      version = __version__,
      install_requires = ['prestans', 'Click>=5.1', 'Jinja2>=2.2.8'],
...
)
```

The questions I have area:

- Is this a legitimate / right thing to do? Or is there a better way to handle this?
- Will this work when I use `python setup.py sdist upload` to publish a release? (Pretty ahrd to test this without stuffing my pypi listing up, unless of course there's a dry run option I've missed out on)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can test by uploading to the testpypi server. Pretty much the same commands, but provide an extra `-i https://testpypi.python.org/pypi`parameter for all commands. [This guide](http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html) mentions it. Be sure to delete your uploads from the test server though, as google indexes it. In my case it ranked higher on google than the actual pypi page ;)

Comment: @m00am thanks for that, very handy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it is the right thing to do. In fact, IMHO, it looks like a not so clean way to do it. The best thing to do would be to have install_requires in `setup.py` for package installation and a `requirements.txt` file that lists all the packages necessary to recreate your development environment.

You can check this link for a clear differentiation:

https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.io/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements

Comment: I did think about separating the developer tools into a separate repository all together. I would rather append to the same name space e.g `prestans` and `prestans.devel` and am not sure if it's the right thing to do in two separate distributions. Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Also found some [similar discussions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454691/putting-separate-python-packages-into-same-namespace).

Comment: Found Flask's documentation on writing [extensions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/extensiondev/). Essentially the plugin developer has their own namespace (based on a convention) and Flask injects those into it's own namespace via a registry. 

Long and short of it is that I decided not to get hung up about appending to that namespace and going ahead with something like `prestans_devel` as a separate namespace. In my case since the user will never import this directly in their code it makes very little difference.